# Is it possible to use Serilog in different classes in the same app?

Tags: serilog

I have a project and am using Serilog. I want to create a Log.Logger in one place that sinks to a single file and then use that Log in different classes. My first thought was to create a property in each class and then assign the Logger to the property when I instantiate the object. Serilog is static so that won't work.

Is it possible to have a simple way to have multiple classes log to the same file?

Comment: `class Me { static ILogger _log = Log.ForContext<Me>(); }` will work - can you explain what you want/need different?

Comment: @Ruben Bartelink - I have a handful classes in a project. I want to handle try, catch blocks inside the individual classes and log information and errors inside the individual class methods themselves rather than in the main Form1 logic. I know that I could set up Serilog to sink to separate files for each class but that would make reading log files difficult. Ultimately, I plan on spinning these classes off into private NuGet packages to be reused in other projects.

Comment: waaaait - there can be only one global static logger, `Log.Logger`. For libraries, they can feed events in there, or you can accept an `ILogger` as input e.g. in class ctors. If you want stuff to actually be in separate files, that's kinda a separate question - the entries can flow through the same pipeline but be split by `SouceContext` when routed and emitted. If you want to explore via chat, gitter.im might be the best place